# Looking for an ultrafast data store to perform intersect operations

Tags: arrays, set, redis, intersection, key-value

I've been using Redis for a while as a backend for Resque and now that I'm looking for a fast way to perform intersect operation on large sets of data, I decided to give Redis a shot.

I've been conducting the following test:

— **x**, **y** and **z** are Redis sets, they all contain approx. 1 million members (random integers taken from a seed array containing 3M+ members).

— I want to intersect **x y** and **z**, so I'm using *sintersectstore* (to avoid overheating caused by data retrieval from the server to the client)

```
sinterstore r x y z
```

— the resulting set (**r**) contains about half a million members, Redis computes this set in approximately half a second.

Half a second is not bad, but I would need to perform such calculations on sets that could contain more than a billion members each.

I haven't tested how Redis would react with such enormous sets but I assume it would take a lot more time to process the data.

Am I doing this right? Is there a faster way to do that?

Notes:

— native arrays aren't an option since I'm looking for a distributed data store that would be accessed by several workers.

— I get these results on a 8 cores @3.4Ghz Mac with 16GB of RAM, disk saving has been disabled on the Redis configuration.

Comment: Will you have the memory to store several sets of billions of items? I doubt it. I would use SINTER rather than SINTERSTORE. Complexity of the intersection algorithm depends on the size of the smallest set. If you have 0.5 secs for 1M, you can expect at least 500 secs for 1B (probably more).

Comment: @DidierSpezia: It depends on the size it requires to store one integer in a Redis set. Do you have any idea? One thing that I'm afraid of, is that I think Redis stores members as strings (UTF-8 strings) which obviously requires more space. Also, the reason why I'm using SINTERSTORE is that I want to keep the data on Redis while performing all successive operations in order to avoid unnecessary data transfer from the server to the client. The resulting keys would  then be expired to free memory.

Comment: Ignoring the hash table itself, each integer item in a set takes a dict entry (32 bytes) and a Redis object (16 bytes), so you can expect a 1B set to take at least 48 GB of memory on a 64 bits platform.

Comment: The size of the hash table itself is not negligible because of incremental rehashing, so it can take 8-16 GB on top of the 48 GB. On my Linux box, a sets of 10M integers takes 630 MB.

Comment: @DidierSpezia: I though Sets (not Sorted Sets) were storing only the actual objects a bit like an array would do but it looks like I'm wrong. Also, regarding 32bits vs 64bits: considering that Redis is a single-threaded server, what would be the benefit of running one big instance allocating huge amounts of memory (thus requiring running the 64bits version) versus having multiple 32 bits interconnected instances?

Comment: The benefit is you can access all your data from a Redis command. How can you calculate an intersection if the sets are stored in different Redis instances? Redis cannot do it.

Comment: @DidierSpezia: you are right, seems that Redis only accept replication (master-slave schema) and not distribution over many instances. Any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that ***bitmaps*** are your best hope.

In my experience, **redis** is a perfect server for bitmaps; you would use the ***string*** data structure (one of the five data structures available in redis)

many or perhaps all of the operations you will need to perform are available out-of-the-box in redis, as atomic operations

the redis ***setbit*** operation has time complexity of O(1)

In a typical implementation, you would hash your array values to offset values on the bit string, then set each bit at its corresponding offset (or *index)*; like so:

```
>>> r1.setbit('k1', 20, 1)
```

the first argument is the key, the second is the offset (index value) and the third is the value at that index on the bitmap.

to find if a bit is set at this offset (20), call *getbit* passing in the key for the bit string.

```
>>> r1.getbit('k1', 20)
```

then on those bitmaps, you can of course perform the usual bitwise operations e.g., logical AND, OR, XOR.