# redis: what's the fastest way to intersect

Tags: redis

I've been using sinter which does intersection of unordered integer sets. Is there any faster way of doing intersection given that I wouldn't mind sorting beforehand (or performing any other preprocessing)?

**EDIT:**
Found some info [here][1]

**EDIT2:**
Bounty for specific answer: is zinterstore faster than sinter? Benchmarking would be cool too.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Fast answer

In theory the intersection of lists has complexity O(N) where N is the cardinality of the smallest set.

Use SET ([SINTER](http://redis.io/commands/sinter)/[SINTERSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/sinterstore)) if have sparsed data / should keep RAM low (**O(N*M)**) and use BITSET([SETBIT](http://redis.io/commands/setbit)/[BITOP](http://redis.io/commands/bitop)) in all other cases (**O(N)**. Like in your edit one [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471078/looking-for-an-ultrafast-data-store-to-perform-intersect-operations).

## BITSET

The Redis BIT key operations have complexity O(N), there N is the cardinality of the smallest key. And the bitops has very best execution speed based on CPU cache (look at `bitops.c` sources). So this can be the absolute winner in you have not sparsed data or if memory not important for you ([here is](https://web.archive.org/web/20181116192407/http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-strings/) more about strings in Redis).

## ZSET vs SET (zinterstore vs sinter)

Do not use ZSET (zinterstore) is you have a plain list of integers and want to intersect them. Sorted set in Redis is a complex structure their keys stored in  `ziplist` or `skiplist` internal encodings. The last one used to store sorted scores but keys stored in other structures. In case of ZSET intersection always much complicated with comparison SET:

> **ZSET** intersection: **O(N * K) + O(M * log(M))** worst case with N being the smallest input sorted set, K being the number of input sorted sets and M being the number of elements in the resulting sorted set.
>
> **SET** intersection: **O(N * M)** worst case where N is the cardinality of the smallest set and M is the number of sets. Actually math-based minimum in theory.

SET uses `dict` / `intset` data structures to store data and in your case (unordered integer sets) `intset` would be used. `Intset` the most memory save the structure in Redis. And have the best read speed with comparison to `ziplist` (doubly linked list, [more about this data structure internals here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180103011234/http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-hash-part-2-and-list/)).